# How to get ack use the nio?

Tags: java, tcp, nio, nio2

How to use the **NIO library** to get the **ACK** field and use it to reconnect the sever problems . I've tried some way , but it doesn't work .

Comment: Please explain you question with more details.

Comment: Sorry about that .I want to build a socket connection and get the ACK field to  
judge the situation about not accept the ACK field.

Comment: It is not practical to do this in Java.  Or indeed, in any user-space application. (Indeed, I suspect that this would be a TCP protocol violation ... if your goal is to reconnect a broken connection.)  But why are you trying to do this?  What are you trying to achieve?  I suspect that this is an XY Problem: http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the answer . I have the same thought about these problems , but i need learn more about  these things to make sure I am not wrong.

Comment: Well I don't think we can help you / answer your question unless you explain clearly what you are trying to do .... and why.

Comment: Tell about the ACK is not available in Java is already enough. Actually , i want to  know how  TCP  things worked in NIO  or  how to achieve the connecting work in low level.  @StephenC

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no TCP API in existence (short of rolling your own with raw sockets) that delivers the ACK to your application, and there is no reason why it should  do so. TCP is a streaming protocol, not. a message protocol.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your answering.It is very helpful.